# Deploying a XAP file into ~/ClientBin using VSeWSS

Tags: silverlight, sharepoint, deployment, vsewss

I have a **SharePoint** (using VSeWSS 1.3) project that creates **a WSP file which installs my custom content types**. One of the type also installs a custom version of DispForm.aspx which is hosting a **Silverlight control, located in the ~/ClientBin as a XAP file.**

Is there a way in the **ListDefinition.xml** file to instruct VSeWSS to **deploy my XAP file into ~/ClientBin** as part of the WSP solution? I know how to deploy images to the TEMPLATES\images folder, but not to ~/ClientBin .

Philipp

Answer (score 1):

To get the XAP file into the ClientBin directory you could try this. Let the solution deploy the XPA file to a folder within the TEMPLATE directory (12 Hive). With a FeatureRecevier that triggers on the FeatureInstalled event you could then copy the XAP file from its location in the sub folder of the TEMPLATE directory to the ClientBin folder.

The FeatureUnistalled event can be used to remove the XAP file from the ClientBin folder when the solution is retracted.

Answer (score 0):

WSP can place the Files in following locations

1. Any Sub Folder inside 12 Hive
2. GAC
3. Bin directory of the Web Application.

Considering the above I recommand you to Change the Location where you keep the XAP file. You can think about placing it in the _Layouts. That is how I Did